# The file bcf does not contain any citations

Tags: biblatex, biber

Does anybady know what this mean?

INFO - This is Biber 2.15 (beta) INFO - Logfile is 'NewThesis.blg' INFO - Reading 'NewThesis.bcf' INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0 WARN - The file 'NewThesis.bcf' does not contain any citations! INFO - Writing 'NewThesis.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8' INFO - Output to NewThesis.bbl INFO - WARNINGS: 1

I have been stuck for hours. I checked all my reference files, but I am not a pro and I don't know where to look...

Please help! I have a massive deadline

Comment: did you actually use \cite or \textcite in your document?

Comment: You will only get any output in the bibliography if you `\...cite`'d (`\cite`, `\parencite`, `\textcite`, `\footcite`, ...) any references. If you want to add an entry to the bibliography without citing it, you can use `\nocite{<entrykey>}` (if you want to add all entries from your `.bib` file to the bibliography, use `\nocite{*}`). At the moment it is hard to say what is going on at your end. Maybe you can delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`), then rerun LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX and tell us about the warnings and errors you get.

Comment: If that does not help, you'll have to show us what you are doing in your document by posting a short, but compilable example document that reproduces your bibliography setup. A so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Yes, I use \cite{} and it has been working fine.

Comment: In my total ignorance I saved everything, I turned off my computer and then rerun Latex and Biber.

Comment: It worked. the idea was that it was not properly generating the file .bcf. I don't know if it makes sense, but now it is running fine

Comment: @moewe thank you! I did not delete the files but it worked

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was resolved by restarting and recompiling (see comments above). In the current state it is not possible to diagnose the problem any further.